# How to collapse current group in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, gesturedetector

I have a fragment that represents one tab of my project. This fragment hosts an ExpandableListAdapater. The expandable list is simply one TextView child per group that displays some information.

What I am trying to achieve is to implement a double tap on the TextView that is expanded. Upon double tapping the TextView, it will collapse that group.

I have tried to collapse the group inside the adapter but it gets a SO for some reason. I know I have to implement a GestureDetector but I can't seem to implement this inside the adapter or even the fragment.

My fragment:

```
public class FragmentProgramInfo extends Fragment
{
View view;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapterProgramInfo expandableListAdapterProgramInfo;

public FragmentProgramInfo()
    {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_program_info, container, false);
    return view;
    }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    expandableListAdapterProgramInfo = new ExpandableListAdapterProgramInfo(getActivity());
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ELV_program_info_list);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapterProgramInfo);
    }
}
```

My Adapater:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapterProgramInfo extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
Activity context;
View masterView;
private String[] listGroups;
private String[][] listChilds;

public ExpandableListAdapterProgramInfo(Activity context)
    {
    this.context = context;
    interfaceExpandableListAdapterProgramInfo = (InterfaceExpandableListAdapterProgramInfo) context;
    masterView = context.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    /// Intitialize strings of listGroups and listChilds
    }

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int listGroupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(view == null)
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_program_info, viewGroup, false);
    TextView tvListGroupProgramInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TV_list_group_program_info);
    tvListGroupProgramInfo.setText(getGroup(listGroupPosition).toString());
    return view;
    }

@Override
public View getChildView(final int listGroupPosition, final int listChildPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_program_info, viewGroup, false);
    TextView tvListChildProgramInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TV_list_child_program_info);
    tvListChildProgramInfo.setText(listChilds[listGroupPosition][listChildPosition]);
    return view;
    }

/// Override other methods of ELV
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition){
    //collapse the old expanded group, if not the same
    //as new group to expand
    if(groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition){
        listView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
    }

    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);           
    lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
}
```

Hope it helps! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

At first you have to detect the last selected position
You can try some thing like this

```
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;// last index selected
private ExpandableListAdapterProgramInfo expandableListView; //your expandable listview
...

expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
    }
});
```